# how could i distinguish default-parameter method in python

Tags: python, default-parameters

recently,i am learn python.i met a problem when i readed this book named **The_Python_Tutorial**.it's about how to distinguish the method with default parameter.i googled and read other books while i try to solve it,but i failed.if you can help me,plz.
here is my problem:

```
  def f(a,L=[]):
        L.append(a)
        return L
    print(f(1))
    print(f(2))
    print(f(3))
```

it shows

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,3]
```

so i changed another way

```
 def g(a,L=None):
            if L is None:
                L=[]
            L.append(a)
            return L
     print (g(1))
     print (g(2))
     print (g(3))
```

it just shows

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

how it happens?too weird.all i want to know is that why diff betwween this two method and sommeone can explain it. thanks.

Comment: Nope. It works fine for me... Please check the output again.

Comment: @Blender: the "Least Astonishment" question is related. But how is it a duplicate? How do you explain `[1] [1] [1]` output?

Comment: @Mark: [edit] your question and fix the indentation of your Python code. Indentation is significant in Python.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I couldn't reproduce that output in three Python versions, so I'm assuming it's a bug with OP's test code.

Comment: @Blender: exactly my point. Instead of closing the question as a duplicate, the error should be pointed out.

Comment: @thefourtheye: I checked I am getting similar result as depicted in OP

Comment: @MaNKuR Could you please show in ideone.com? This is what I tried http://ideone.com/1crw1l

Comment: @thefourtheye : Here is the result http://ideone.com/wARWlJ

Comment: if I understand OP correctly, he is asking the diff between method `f()` and `g()` why its getting different result.

Comment: @MaNKuR: it doesn't reproduce OP's case. In your code `g(n)` leads to `[n]` but OP shows `g(n)` -> `[1]`.

Comment: oh yes.... I missed this :)

Comment: @MaNKuR yes,just like you say,i just want to know the diff between this two method and why?

Comment: thanks to everone,i got my answer.

Comment: @Blender: it was a duplicate after all (OP changed `[1] [1] [1]` output to the expected `[1] [2] [3]`)